# PhpStorm autocompletes with classes that do not actually exist

Tags: php, phpstorm, httpexception

I use PhpStorm 9.0.1. When I write to throw a new Exception PhpStorm is showing for Exceptions the `HttpException` class. So I can autocomplete my code and have the following line:

```
throw new HttpException($message);
```

But when I execute the code it shows an error message that `HttpException` class is not found. Does anyone know why the HttpException class is not found or how can I set the PhpStorm to show on autocomplete only the classes that do exist?

By the way if I `ctrl+click` above the `HttpException` PhpStorms opens a file with path

```
PhpStorm/plugins/php/lib/php.jar!/com/jetbrains/php/lang/psi/stubs/data/http.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the HttpException class is not found

That exception is part of [HTTP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) which is not part of default PHP installation -- you will have to download/install it separately.

> ...how can I set the PhpStorm to show on autocomplete only the classes that do exist?

Well .. that extension does exist if PHP's HTTP extension is enabled.

In code completion IDE will offer **all** classes that it knows about (especially if such classes are part of bundled stubs). ATM you cannot say "I do not want to see stuff from that stub file" for bundled stuff. You will have to filter out such entries yourself.

Comment: To complicate matters even further, links to the HTTP extension return 404. O.o

Comment: @Christian As of 2017.2 you can disable unwanted built-in stubs from being offered in code completion -- it's configurable at `PHP Runtime` tab -- next to `PHP Include path`

Comment: Yes, but this has to be done on a per-project basis... considering this extension doesn't exist, (and PHP people seem to want to erase it from memory), might as well remove it as well (or at least make it available only when selecting old PHP flavours in project settings).

Comment: @Christian I gave you the possibility of removing it right now. If you think that this module/extension is no longer available to PHP/whatever (and stubs should be removed etc) -- please complain to JetBrains at their [Issue Trakcer](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and not me :)

Comment: Yes, true... I didn't mean to complain, but just to give the complete picture to anyone looking into this just as I did. Also, for the record, I did open a ticket yesterday as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39363